# java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 32 Broken pipe

Tags: websphere, spring-rest

```
I am getting given below error in application log, even though request processing completed successfully ie Producer process the request successfully .
```

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 32  Broken pipe
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.<init>(AsyncLibrary.java:924) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:937) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:951) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncChannel.multiIO(AbstractAsyncChannel.java:482) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.write(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:478) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.writeAIOSync(AioSocketIOChannel.java:353) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPWriteRequestContextImpl.processSyncWriteRequest(AioTCPWriteRequestContextImpl.java:126) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.write(TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.java:122) ~[?:CCX.CF [o1800.01]]
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.flushCloseDown(SSLUtils.java:214) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.shutDownSSLEngine(SSLUtils.java:126) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.cleanup(SSLConnectionLink.java:228) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.close(SSLConnectionLink.java:172) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.close(HttpInboundLink.java:899) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.wsspi.channel.base.InboundApplicationLink.close(InboundApplicationLink.java:58) ~[?:CCX.CF [o1800.01]]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.close(WCChannelLink.java:333) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.releaseChannelLink(WCChannelLink.java:503) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:405) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:694) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at <unknown class>.<unknown method>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
```

```
Spring 5.3.13  ( REST controller)
IBM WAS 9.0 
JDK 1.8
```

Consumer received **504 gateway time out error** - since java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 32  Broken pipe in Producer log.

What could be the reason for RC: 32 Broken pipe ?

Answer (score 0):

For asynchronous web services, the client asynchronous response listener opens a socket with the default value of seven seconds to persist and listen for asynchronous responses. If the server operation takes longer than the default value, the server or client might receive the following exception:

java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 32  Broken pipe

This exception occurs because the persistent read timeout limit is exceeded on the client and subsequently, the connection is closed.

Use this property(HttpInboundPersistReadTimeout) when you are reading large data, or at times when the network is slow such that it takes more than the default value of seven seconds on the server side to read the data. If you receive the broken pipe exception on the server side, increase the value of this time out property.

Comment: Apigee gateway time out is 2 mins , and Producer processing time less then 1 minutes only , even though i am getting this error .

Comment: As per the given below IBM WAS doc , its recommends to increase the HttpInboundPersistReadTimeout from 7 seconds in order to avoid the broken pipe error.https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=services-http-transport-custom-properties-web-applications

Answer (score 0):

My application (Spring REST) based on multithreading .so one or more thread try to writing single log file - which is cause an issue .

```
1.I have changed Log level from DEBUG to ERROR.
2.Implemented 3 log file with Asynchronous Loggers.
3.Changed HttpInboundPersistReadTimeout from 7 seconds to 10 seconds in IBM WAS console.
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=services-http-transport-custom-properties-web-applications

Now no more time out error.